# Is it possible to bind a React.js rendered link to a legacy jQuery function?

Tags: reactjs

In a React component, I tried rendering

```
<a id="help" onClick={this.handleHelp}>{_('Help')}</a>
```

and I put

```
this.handleHelp = this.handleHelp.bind(this);
```

in the constructor. So I want to bind that click to our legacy javascript Help library.

I tried

```
handleHelp(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.Help.init('some_value');
}
```

When clicked, absolutely nothing happens, including no messages nor errors in developer console. The Help jquery script is loaded at the time. On init, that binds `$("#help").on("click", showHelp);` so I was hoping I could somehow trigger that click in the handleHelp handler, but I've not been able to figure out how.

UPDATE: Thanks to responders, I figured out to just add a call to the window.Help.showHelp() function into my handleHelp, after window.Help.init(). (Obvious, in hindsight.)

Comment: "On init, that binds `$("#help").on("click", showHelp);`" - so the call to `init()` you run is just setting up an onClick handler for elements with the class "help" that will run `showHelp()`? Is that right? Is there another function on your Help object that you can call to actually trigger the help?

Comment: So there's no need to have `("#help").on("click", showHelp);` anywhere.. but are you saying that your react click function isn't triggering? What's `window.Help.init('some_value');` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Both of you, thanks... those were the clues I needed.